# "user:one-time-login-url" token not getting replaced by token_replace

Tags: 7, tokens, emails

I'm trying to send e-mails to users manually by using the hook_mail_alter hook. The following is my function in its entirety:

```
function custom_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
    $email = '[user:name],

A site administrator at [site:name] has created an account for you. You may now log in by clicking this link or copying and pasting it to your browser:

[user:one-time-login-url]

This link can only be used once to log in and will lead you to a page where you can set your password.

After setting your password, you will be able to log in at [site:login-url] in the future using:

username: [user:name]
password: Your password

--  [site:name] team';

    $account = $message['params']['account'];
    $uid = $account->uid;

    $_user = user_load($uid);

    dpm(token_replace($email, array('user'=>$_user)));
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Peter,

A site administrator at Website has created an account for you. You may now log in by clicking this link or copying and pasting it to your browser:

[user:one-time-login-url]

This link can only be used once to log in and will lead you to a page where you can set your password.

After setting your password, you will be able to log in at http://localhost/website/user in the future using:

username: Peter
password: Your password

--  Website team
```

As you can see, things like [user:name], [site:name], and [site:login-url] are properly processed. The only token that isn't processed is [user:one-time-login-url]. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: Just for reference, the token *does* get processed in the Welcome e-mails that's sent out by the system automatically, so the token module is active *and* working... It just doesn't seem to get processed when I manually call token_replace().

Comment: Do you have the token.module enabled? It looks like that token is defined in [token_token_info()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--token--token.tokens.inc/function/token_token_info/7) and not in user_token_info().

Comment: Yes, Token module is enabled, and I'm using the latest Beta7... This is rather odd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To replace that token, you need to call `token_replace()` as `token_replace($email, array('user' => $_user), array('callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE))`.

The function [user_mail_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_mail_tokens/7) is described in the documentation as:

> Token callback to add unsafe tokens for user mails.
>
> This function is used by the [token_replace()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--token.inc/function/token_replace/7) call at the end of [_user_mail_text()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/_user_mail_text/7) to set up some additional tokens that can be used in email messages generated by [user_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_mail/7).

The code used by `_user_mail_text()` to call that callback is the following one.

```
// We do not sanitize the token replacement, since the output of this
// replacement is intended for an e-mail message, not a web browser.
return token_replace($text, $variables, array('language' => $language, 'callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE));
```

The Token module is not necessary to replace tokens, in Drupal 7. The code to replace tokens is part of the Drupal 7 core code; the Token module in Drupal 7 defines extra tokens that Drupal core modules don't define.