# How to get one time URL when we are writing hook_mail_alter?

Tags: 8, users, emails

My Question is already present [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/userone-time-login-url-token-not-getting-replaced-by-token-replace) but the previously given answer for my question can applied to Drupal 7 and I can not use the same solution in Drupal 8.

I hope it is okay not put the same question once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo! Found the Solution myself:

```
    function custom_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
      if (!empty($message['id']) && $message['id'] == 'user_password_reset') {
        $token_service = \Drupal::token();
        $language_interface = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
        $account = $message['params']['account'];  
        $one_time_url_token = '[user:one-time-login-url]';  
        $one_time_url = $token_service->replace($one_time_url_token, ['user' => $account], ['langcode' => $language_interface->getId(), 'callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'clear' => TRUE]);  
      }
    }
```